# ADB only shows 1 device (MEMU, NOX). How do I access multiple instances?

Tags: android, adb

I want to run ADB commands on Android emulators (like MEMU and NOX).
But when I use

```
adb devices
```

it only shows:

```
List of devices attached
127.0.0.1:21513 device
```

Even though I have multiple emulators running with their multiple instance manager.
Why are 2 different devices displayed as 1 IP address ?
And why is it the IP address and not like emulator-5555 (i saw this in another post)
How do I access the specific emulator ?

Im fairly new to ADB (since yesterday) and I tried running ADB commands the whole day now but I cant access multiple emulators. For 1 emulator it works but not for multiple.

Solution:
For MEmu i have got it to work after enabling USB Debugging on the emulators. Sadly for Nox it is still displaying only one device, even after enabling it there too.

Comment: Did you enable USB debugging in the Android settings?

Comment: Names like emulator-5555 come from the queue based emulator included in Android SDK. Your emulators are different. Nox even includes it's own version of adb IIRC, not sure if nox is compatible with adb from Android SDK, may be the nox developers have modified it so that it only shows NOX instances.

Comment: @IsidroRodriguez Yes, I enabled it on Nox but only 1 is showing up. Now I tried it on MEmu aswell and on there it displays 2 emulators in "adb devices". I will just use MEmu then, but im still wondering why they dont show up in Nox. Thanks for your help

Comment: Different emulators may show up on different adb's as they are not the standard one.